# Python 3.1: Syntax Error for Everything! (Mac OS X)

Tags: python, macos, shell, syntax-error, python-idle

I updated to Python 3.1.3 (I've got OS X 10.6).

If I type `python` in Terminal, I get a working 2.6.1 environment.
If I type `python3` in Terminal, I get a 3.1.3 environment. Everything looks fine until I do something. If I try to run `print "hello"`, I get a syntax error.
This problem is the same in IDLE.

I tried deleting everything for 3.1 and then reinstalling, but it hasn't worked.

Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since when does `print "hello"` equate to everything?

Comment: for someone who is just starting `print "hello"` **is** everything. I got bitten by the same "bug".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3, you need to use Print as a function:

```
print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3.x, [`print` is a function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), so use

```
print("Hello")
```

instead.